# For text-align:right; in TD, why does "style" work and "class" not?

Tags: css

If I include this in a table cell:

```
<td style="text-align: right; font-style: italic; color: maroon;">...
```

the contents of the cell are aligned as I expect.

If I include the following CSS:

```
.right-notice { text-align: right; font-style: italic; color: maroon; }
```

and this cell:

```
<td class=".right-notice">...
```

the contents of the cell are **not** right aligned.

Why is this? What don't I know?

If I change the CSS to replace text-align with float, that works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a class selector that matches `right-align` but your class name is `.right-align`

While it is possible to match a class name that includes a `.` character, it would make more sense to change the name of the class.

While you are at it you should [change the class name to describe meaning instead of presentation](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames).

Comment: Okay, I'll go look for that. Thanks.

Comment: I usually follow the semantic advice. For the purpose of this question I simplified.

Comment: I made the rule specific:

    .generic-table td { padding: 5px 8px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; }
    .generic-table td.special-notice-right { text-align: right; font-style: italic; color: maroon; }

Not only did I not get right alignment, I didn't get the font styles.

Comment: Sorry, that comment is a mess. I'm new to StackOverflow as a poster. Should I have edited my original post to show this new variant?

Answer (score 3):

change `<td class=".right-notice">` to `<td class="right-notice">` (there mustn't be a dot).

Comment: Oops, that was a typo here. The code doesn't actually look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's right aligned regardless if you set the style using the style attribute or a class name. I tried your code (with the correction of the class name in the tag), and the text is right aligned just fine.

If you have a page where it doesn't work, you have to look for the reason somewhere else. Make sure that the style sheet is actually working. Look for other settings in the style sheet that may override the class, either because they have higher specificity or because they have the same specificity and comes later in the style sheet.

Comment: Right. I'll look further. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'm getting more thick-headed with age. This turns out to be just a piece of stupidity on my part. In this particular area of the site I have two generic table classes. I was changing the CSS for the wrong one!